# Conversion from hex into normal char and doing string manipulation?

Tags: c, string

We have a packet capture programming where the whole packet is represented by the this input const u_char *p into the function. We have managed to convert it from hex into readable characters. My challenge now how to store into another array where I need further string processing on it? I am trying to use this method but not sure is this correct way to go ? But this seems not too be dynamic either.

```
char all[1500];

    for(i = 0; i < h->caplen; i++)
    {
          printf("%02X ", p[i]);
          printf("\n");
          sprintf(all,"%02X ",p[i]);
    }
```

For part of the packet in hex is this 474554202f6d61696c2f20485454502f312e310d0a but when we view is this in normal characters is this GET /mail/ HTTP/1.1\r\n. My challenge is to pick the url where I need to check if there get or post and end with http/1.1 or http/1.0 ?

Syntax for extraction

```
 char *getPointer = strstr (all, "GET"); 
 char *httpPointer = strstr (all, "HTTP/1.");
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a conversion?

Comment: I have given a full example of what I am looking into exactly ?

Comment: So, are you getting the string "47" (0x3437) and you're converting it to 'G' (0x47)?

Comment: Yes from "47" to "G" with the specifier "%02". So my challenge is to read through the whole of the array *p and look for the the url if exist. The rule to check if exist is to check if the word get or post or head exist and in between will be the url and ending with either http/1.1 or http/1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string (char *) to binary (hex).  Hex array will 1/2 the length of char array.  Use `strstr ()` to parse hex array for tokens (e.g. "GET").  You're method, so far, is the way to go.

Comment: so my method so far is on the track thank you but I feel is a problem here char all[1500]; isnt this static? Can this be dynamic too based on this value h->caplen; ? So what should I pass into the strstr is the char all array rite ?

Comment: I guess this how I need user strstr (all, "GET")) or strstr (s1, "POST")) how to extract the url if exist?

Comment: `char all[1500]` is created on the stack if it's a local variable, static if `static` keyword is used within a function or if defined outside a function.  You can use `malloc()` if you want the array size to be dynamic.  `strstr()` will return a `char *` to a substring if it exists in a string.

Comment: What is the difference with using static or not? I think malloc is going to cumbersome cause I need to allocate then again release guess I will create on big array and leave it. I am planning this if (strstr (all, "GET") !==NULL && strstr (all, "HTTP/1.")) then I do url extraction what you say about this method is this logic fine?

Comment: Static would probably be better if used often.  Your logic sounds good. You might be able to optimize it, but that could come after you get it working.

Comment: I am actually lost between to use static or not? What is good part of using static in your experience? From memory perspective I am going to create each char all[1500]; for every captured packet what is your opinion on this?

Comment: I need you help on the next part how can I extract once I determine my if (strstr (all, "GET") !==NULL && strstr (all, "HTTP/1.")) ? Any idea I am not too sure on this manipulation ?

Comment: Using static memory will be faster but tie up memory needlessly if not used often.  If you find a keyword substring in the string, `strstr()` will return a pointer to that substring. You need to increment that pointer to the URL yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42093/discussion-between-user2711681-and-bit-fiddling-code-monkey)

Comment: In my case if I never use static is that ok? Secondly I have updated my question with the syntax for extraction can give me your comment on how to move next from here not too sure with the syntax I know the logic well now.

Comment: Is the logic now is *getPointer+3 till the *httpPointer. How to extract all the character and put into a variable so I can insert into my db now